# How to automatically fill data in an invoice in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am sharing [this](https://docs.google.com/a/al-ezzi.com/spreadsheets/d/1nMUSuRGUVaNpZV1g9ji7LmqQLZ5AcX0TnDf01LQgM40/edit?usp=sharing) sheet with you so that you can have a look and give me a proper solution. Basically what I want to do it generate an invoice based on the data entered in "Purchases" but I don't know how to do it as the lot numbers aren't always in the proper sequence. Therefore, if you notice in the "Sale & Inventory" sheet, I have to create multiple entries for one invoice. Is there a simpler method where the invoices are generated automatically? I don't want more than 30 lots/invoice.

Thanks,

Huzaifa.

Answer (score 1):

I can't leave a comment to ask a question, so I assumed you'd want all lots from a certain date. Please see the 'Invoice' tab from [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oSPwTWq6bDtnaFvfXJM4lizIXwwkBobMvsvoZbyqTOc/edit?usp=sharing) (I duplicated yours). Changing the yellow drop-downs should fill the invoice for you. You can also create multiple pages so it stays A4 size.

*I also had to make sure column C on the 'Purchases' tab was formatted as a date 'yyyy-mm-dd' by using the 'Format' menu.*

I did this by adding `=QUERY(Purchases!$A$2:$T$500,"Select B where B<>'' and C >= date '"&TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(K3,"[0-9]{6}"),"20##-##-##")&"' and C <= date '"&TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(L3,"[0-9]{6}"),"20##-##-##")&"' limit 30 offset "&IF(M6=1,0,(M6-1)*34)&"",0)` to cell `H8` (highlighted green) in 'Invoices' tab.

How it works:

```
=QUERY(
Purchases!$A$2:$T$500,                  //the data I want to query
"Select B                               //tells it which column i want data from
where B<>''                             //make sure column B is not blank

and C >= date '"&TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(K3,"[0-9]{6}"),"20##-##-##")&"'
                                        //makes sure the date is greater than or equal to
                                        //the start date found in your lot code and formats
                                        //it as 'yyyy-mm-dd' which is necessary for the
                                        //query function

and C <= date '"&TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(L3,"[0-9]{6}"),"20##-##-##")&"'
                                        //makes sure the date is less than or equal to
                                        //the start date found in your lot code and formats
                                        //it as 'yyyy-mm-dd' which is necessary for the
                                        //query function

limit 30                                //restricts the returned results to 30 so it does
                                        //not exceed the number of lines on your invoice

offset "&IF(M6=1,0,(M6-1)*30)&"         //this shows the 'page' of data that you select
")
```

Let me know if you have different criteria for invoices and I can help, but try and see if you can figure it out from [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) first.